# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `remote_image_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Getting this error

in this page

<%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %>
    <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>

Model

```
class Gamepic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :gamepic, GamepicUploader

  private 
    def Gamepic_params
      params.require(:gamepic).permit(:gameid, :gamename, :gamepic, :remote_image_url)
  end
end
```